# How to separately implode data, based on ID or unique NAME?

Tags: laravel, database

I have database like this

| id | name | numbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kathy | 5 |
| 2 | Kathy | 15 |
| 3 | Kathy | 25 |
| 4 | William | 5 |
| 5 | William | 10 |

and I'm trying to retrieve and save it like this

| id | name | numbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kathy | 5.15.25 |
| 2 | William | 5.10 |

So I made a code like this to implode and save the data

```
$arr_name = [];
$arr_numbers = [];
$arr_implode = [];

$data= MyDatabase::all();

foreach ($data as $data) {
    if ($data->name == $data->name) {
        $arr_numbers [] = $data->numbers;
    } else {
        $arr_numbers [] = $data->numbers;
    }

    $arr_implode[$data->name] = implode('.', $arr_numbers);
}
```

but what I get when I use **dd($arr_implode);** is like this, so I haven't tried saving the data in my database.

```
array:2 [▼
    "Kathy" => "5.15.25"
    "William" => "5.15.25.5.10"
]
```

What should I do to get the desired output? sorry, I'm not really good at arrays and stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DB::raw` to format them during the query

e.i.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

return DB::table('table_name')->select([
    DB::raw('ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY name ) as id'),
    'name', 
    DB::raw('group_concat(numbers SEPARATOR ".") as numbers')
])->groupBy('name')->get();
```

**OR**

Just query all the data and format the [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections)

e.i.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$data = DB::table('table_name')->select(['id','name','numbers'])->get();
```

or if you have a model for that table

```
$data = Model::select(['id','name','numbers'])->get();
```

then format it the way you want

```
return $data
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->values()
    ->map( fn ( $item, $key) => [
        'id' => $key+ 1,
        'name' => data_get($item, '0.name'),
        'numbers' => implode('.', $item->pluck('numbers')->all() )
    ]);
```

Comment: `over` may not be available if the user is using MySQL < 8.0